# how to get "run as java application" as a shortcut in the run configuration of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
 import stanford.karel.*;
 public class MidpointFindingKarel extends SuperKarel 
{ 
     public void run()
   {
    move(); 
   }    
}
```

This is my example code.the method run() is inherited from the SuperKarel class.
All i want is to run this code and codes like this as a java application.but when i click on the 'Run as', i see only 'run as java applet' there.how to get the option of 'run as java application there'.i know how to create a run configuration but when i do,that configuration is being applicable only to a particular java file.how to run codes like these without creating a run configuration everytime for a new java file??

Comment: very simple you should have main() to run this class or like wise you can have TestMidpointFindingKarel Class  in that you can use the main () can invoke these functions from Test Class.@srk

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `main()` as

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

For instance you might change your class to

```
public class MidpointFindingKarel extends SuperKarel { 
  public void run() {
    move(); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MidpointFindingKarel mfk = new MidpointFindingKarel();
    mfk.run();
}
```

Comment: This was only meant as an example. Not seeing how your SuperKarel class is defined I have no way of knowing whether it is correct or complete.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you need a

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

method in your class.  It may be that MidpointFindingKarel is used by the main class which is defined somewhere else.  In that case, search for it and run that class.

In essence, Eclipse populates the run menu based on the current class that has focus in the editor.

Once, you have the run configuration set up, you can of course simply right click on the run menu dropdown box and select the class to execute (typically, top-left on the toolbar).

Comment: void main(String[] args)  will this statement  solve the problem??@Jaco Van Niekerk

Comment: @"the unlucky", I've polished it for you... :)

Comment: i tried that and it is not working....and in some versions of eclipse we get the 'run as java application' option even if our code doesn't have a main method...howto get it? @Jaco Van Niekerk

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? ...how exactly are you invoking the "run as" menu? I've been working in Eclipse for nearly 10 years now... I've never seen that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a main method in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Run as Java Application is applicable only to classes having public static main method. Change the code to add main method. You will find the option of run as.